# How to change Simple Calendar Module Output

Tags: component, module

I installed simplecalendar (http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/calendars-a-events/events/simplecalendar) on my site (Joomla 3.2.3) and now I am facing the problem, that the module displays a events like this:

TITLE, LOCATION, DATE, TIME

but I would prefer:

DATE, TIME, LOCATION (possible break) TITLE

I already searched via FTP in *modules/mod_simplecalendar/tmpl/default.php* but this does not seem to have influence on that.
There are some options in the backend for changing the order of the fields displayed, but those seem to apply on the content-side only and not on the module.

(german screenshot)

[image]

Does anyone have a suggestion on this?

Comment: Normally I would suggest a template override the default.php of the module, however the module isn't displaying the result dynamically, so I believe you're going to have to edit a core file for the extension

Comment: I thought the same, but I can't find the correct file to change it.

Comment: I would suggest contacting the developer of this extension ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this, there were acutally more settings in the module configuration giving a order like

```
{NAME} {DATE}
```

etc.

But I've got some more problems with this.

I'll contact the developer as suggested.